# Is git subtree compatible with Gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit, git-subtree

Our git repositories are hosted in Gerrit. A colleague maintains 2 repos `main` and `sub`. He wants to include `sub` inside `main` as a subtree. Here's so far what we have tried:

```
git clone repo_url_main -b dev main
cd main
git subtree add -P foo/bar repo_url_sub master
touch foo/bar/baz.txt
git add .
git commit -m 'foo.bar.baz.tt'
git subtree push -P foo/bar repo_url_sub master
```

The first problem is that `git subtree push` fails because his account does not have the permission to directly push the commits without review. The review is what he wants.

For a non-subtree repo, we use `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master` to create a review change. So we try `git subtree push -P foo/bar repo_url_sub master:refs/for/master` and it fails too. Git complains that `master:refs/for/master` is not a valid ref. I find `git subtree push  -P <prefix> <repository> <ref>` in the manual. The last part is `ref` instead of `refspec`. So `master:refs/for/master` is not expected here.

And then we try `git subtree push -P foo/bar repo_url_sub refs/for/master`. The push succeeds but the result is not expected. A branch `refs/for/master` instead of a review change is created. After several tries, we find it seems whatever the last ref is, it's always expanded to `refs/heads/...`. Even `refs/heads/master` is expanded to `refs/heads/refs/heads/master`.

The workarounds we've thought of so far:

1. Use Google's REPO tool to manage the 2 repos as it's done for AOSP, which needs extra skills and is a bit of overkill.
2. Use `git submodule`, which is more troublesome.
3. Include a local transfer `sub` repo as the subtree in `main`. First `git subtree push` to update `master` in the transfer repo, and then in the transfer repo use `git push repo_url_sub HEAD:refs/for/master` to create review changes. But we can foresee the chaos when many maintainers are involved.

Are there any git options or configs that can instruct `git subtree push` to correctly create review changes in Gerrit? Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordingly with the "git help subtree":

> push
>
> Does a split using the  supplied and then does a
>   git push to push the result to the repository and ref

So I think you could first execute a "git subtree split" followed by a "git push", something like:

```
git subtree split --prefix=foo/bar -b split
git push repo_url_sub split:refs/for/master
```